# Android licenses not accepted. flutter doctor --android-licenses command not working

Tags: flutter, android-studio, sdk

[I have run the flutter doctor android licenses command and accepted all the licenses, and it gave me the "All SDK package licenses accepted" message. but when I run the flutter doctor command again the problem wasn't solved.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDnED.png)

Comment: did you reopen the terminal? or try to restart the machine and then try again?

Comment: yes I did, but nothing changed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.